# Testing the router for invalid routes

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, routes, functional-testing

I want to test all twig files, and controllers--basically everything that uses the Router to test the helper functions for invalid route calls.

Things such as `{{ path('fails_right_here') }}` and `$controller->generateUrl('nope_again');`

You could say that this belongs to the functional tests, which i got--but.. it doesnt make sense to write scenarios for every single link thats out there. It makes more sense to write one scenario that leads to editing a article for example, and all the other 10+ routes that lead to this same scenario to be automatically validated. Or else i need to write 100's of tests for something silly :)

Any way to do this currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to test all the paths like that. Simply trying to render a link to a broken path in Twig will trigger an error, so you're already testing in just crawling any page that does that.